# Trigger Refresh from subClass to mainClass

Tags: python, qgis, pyqgis

I have a main dialog which displays information, and it also has a edit data button. When the edit data button is clicked a new dialog appears where you can edit and change and data and press OK to save it into the txt file that stores the data. I'm trying to find a way to cause that data on the main dialog to refresh when the the OK button on the other dialog is pressed or when the data in the txt file is changed. But the first way is more preferred as it is more general.

Main Dialog

```
from .list_management import ListManagement
class MainDialog(QDialog): 

    def __init__(self, iface, parent=None, flags=Qt.WindowFlags()):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent, flags)
        uic.loadUi(UI_PATH, self)
        self.ListManage_dialog_instance = ListManagement(self.iface)
        self.manage_button.clicked.connect(self.manage_tab)

    #Database Management Tab
    def manage_tab(self):
        self.ListManage_dialog_instance.execDialog()
```

Manage Dialog

```
class ListManagementDialog(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, iface, parent=None, flags=Qt.WindowFlags()):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent, flags)
        uic.loadUi(UI_PATH, self)
        self.iface = iface
        ###edit###

    def ok_pressed(self):
        self.writedata()
        self.close()

class ListManagement(object):
    def execDialog(self):
        self.dialog = ListManagementDialog(self.iface, self.iface.mainWindow())
        self.dialog.show()
```

Comment: just update the elements in the main dialog directly from the sub dialog - don't store the state of your plugin in a text file

Comment: How can I access the main dialog from the sub dialog?

Comment: make it a class variable, pass it in as an argument...